# how to represent nested 'if' to one line python comprehension

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, nested

I have a logic:

```
dic = {.....}
if x in dic:
    do sth
else:
    dic[x] = 0
    do sth (same as previous)
```

how can I change this logic to one line comprehension?

Comment: By in the dictionary, do you mean keys or values?

Comment: Comprehensions usually loop over something -- maybe the keys of the dicitonary, or some other list -- what are you looping over?  In other words, where are the `x` values coming from?  Also, what does `sth` do, or what does it need to do its job?

Comment: Also, couldn't this just be written as `if x not in dic: dic[x] = 0; <do sth>` -- not one line, but the same flow.

Answer (score 0):

Two obvious ways: `setdefault` and `defaultdict`:

```
dic = { ... }
dic.setdefault(x, 0)
# do sth
```

and

```
dic = defaultdict(int, { ... })
# do sth, nonexistent keys are magically set to 0.
```